# jQuery Mobile form post issues, PHP warning: (expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, jquery-mobile, mysqli

**home.html file:**

Two simple jQ Mobile pages with a header and fixed footers. The form is on page one. I haven't added any stipulations like "password must match confirm password" for now. I just want to get it working with the DB first i.e. store in DB.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html>
   <head>
   <!-- Include meta tag to ensure proper rendering and touch zooming -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <!-- Include jQuery Mobile stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://example.net/Login/styles.css"> 
   <!-- Include the jQuery library -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
   <!-- Include the your Ajax-ify file -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://example.net/Login/functions.js"></script> 
  <!-- Include the jQuery Mobile library -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
 </head>
    <body>
                  <!--                      -->
                  <!-- Page One starts here -->
                  <!--                      -->

 <div data-role="page" id="pageone">
 <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
     <h1>Welcome</h1>
 </div> 

 <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
  <br>
  <br>
              <!-- Form starts here -->
  <form id="NewForm" method="post" action="include.php">  
         <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="E.g. JoeB95">
  <br>
         <label>Email</label> 
   <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E.g. Joe@email.com">
  <br>
         <label>Password</label> 
  <input type="password" name="password_1" placeholder="E.g. 8969-545a-r3">
  <br>
  <!--Submit button goes below here -->                                                                                     
  <div id="register"><input type="submit" name="register" data-inline="true" value="Submit"></div>
  </form>
    <br>
    <p>Already a member?</p> <a href="#pagetwo">Sign In</a>
    <br> 
    <span id="result"></span>
    <br>
  </div>  

  <div data-role="footer" id="foot" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
    <h1>footer</h1>
  </div>  
  </div>   
                        <!--   Page One ends here    -->
                        <!--                         -->
                        <!--   Page Two starts here  -->
                                                

 <div data-role="page" id="pagetwo">
 <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
     <h1>Welcome</h1>
 </div> 

 <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
  <br>
  <br>
 <p>Not a member?</p> <a href="#pageone">Signup</a>
  <br>
 </div> 

  <div data-role="footer" id="foot" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
  <h1>footer</h1>
 </div>  
 </div>
```

**functions.js file:** (Ajax-ify)

Code for Ajax-ifying the form is below. I'm not sure if any errors exist here.

```
// AJAX-ify the form
$(document).on("pagecreate","#pageone",function()
{

$("#register").click( function() {
  $.post( $("#NewForm").attr("action"),
     $("#NewForm :input").serializeArray(),
        function(info){ $("#result").html(info);
  });
});

$("#NewForm").submit( function() {
   return false;
  });
});
```

**db.php file:**

This code does work, as it connects with the DB and I've used it before.

```
 <?php

 //put your connection code here
      $servername = 'localhost';
      $username = 'admin_example';
      $password = '123456-7';
      $dbname = 'example_DB';
    
    // create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    echo "Connected successfully, <br>";
 ?>
```

**include.php file:**

This is where I believe the issues are. In the error_log, it points to lines 8 and 11 as the problem areas;

> PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in public_html/Login/include.php on line 8
>
> PHP Warning:  mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in public_html/Login/include.php on line 11

I know there are similar topics regarding these errors, but I couldn't relate it directly to mine. Can anyone suggest what the problem is and what needs to be changed? Thanks.

```
  <?php
  $user  = $_POST['username'];   
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $password_1 = $_POST['password_1']; 

  $access = md5($password_1);   
  $sql = "INSERT INTO users (`username`, `email`, `password`) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password_1')";
  if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
        echo "Successfully Inserted";
  }   else {
        echo ("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn));
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: Unless you're missing code in your example, `$conn` in include.php is null. Even though the connection works in db.php, include.php should not be able to access that `$conn`. Try including/requiring db.php in include.php before the query call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The home.html file calls include.php via the form action.  However, include.php does not call the db.php file.  It appears you're missing something like:

`require db.php;`

in your include.php file.  Without it the $conn variable set in db.php on line 10 is not visible in the include.php file.  That is causing the error.

Comment: Thank you! It was something as simple as that. Cheers.